# In VS Code, when creating a WorkspaceEdit with needsConfirmation, how can I make all the refactor preview checkboxes checked initially?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I apply a `WorkspaceEdit` with `needsConfirmation` set to `true` in the edit metadata i see the Refactor Preview opened which is great. However all checkboxes are unchecked at first. Is there a way to have them all checked instead?

Looked at `BulkEditService` and seems like unchecked checkboxes is the expected behaviour as change is unchecked if it requires confirmation. How do I make all checkboxes checked and still show the Refactor Preview? A code snippet would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [src/vs/workbench/contrib/bulkEdit/browser/preview/bulkEditPreview.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9e3aaa4ac4410cf029e505c922c425b417ea1633/src/vs/workbench/contrib/bulkEdit/browser/preview/bulkEditPreview.ts#L178):

> ```js
> // store inital checked state
> this.checked.updateChecked(edit, !edit.metadata?.needsConfirmation);
> ```

I.e. An individual edit in the workspace edit will be initially checked in the bulk edit preview if its `needsConfirmation` is `false`. So I guess the question now is how to make sure you get the bulk edit preview to show up at all if you want *everything* checked initially... See [the code that calls up the bulk edit preview](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9e3aaa4ac4410cf029e505c922c425b417ea1633/src/vs/workbench/contrib/bulkEdit/browser/bulkEditService.ts#L190), which does this:

> ```js
> if (this._previewHandler && (options?.showPreview || edits.some(value => value.metadata?.needsConfirmation))) {
>   edits = await this._previewHandler(edits, options);
> }
> ```

If everything has `needsConfirmation` set to `false`, then you'd need `options?.showPreview` to be `true`, but when calling the `workspace.applyEdit` API, you don't have control over that option. You can trace that code yourself: [applyWorkspaceEdit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9e3aaa4ac4410cf029e505c922c425b417ea1633/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHost.api.impl.ts#L963), [applyWorkspaceEdit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9e3aaa4ac4410cf029e505c922c425b417ea1633/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHostBulkEdits.ts#L30), [$tryApplyWorkspaceEdit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9e3aaa4ac4410cf029e505c922c425b417ea1633/src/vs/workbench/api/browser/mainThreadBulkEdits.ts#L29). Maybe you could insert a dummy edit that does nothing but has `needsConfirmation` set to `false`?